# LINQ query to filter a list returns nothing

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-objects

Following a tutorial, i've built a LINQ query to filter a List of objects:
`Dim Query = From FilteredItem In Items, FiltSupp In FilteredItem.Suppliers
                    Where ((SuppliersComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString = "All Suppliers" OrElse FiltSupp.CompanyName = SelectedSupplier) And
                           (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtItemCode.Text) OrElse FilteredItem.ItemCode.ToString.Contains(TxtItemCode.Text)) And
                           (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtName.Text) OrElse FilteredItem.Name.ToLower.Contains(TxtName.Text.ToLower)) And
                           (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtPkgCost.Text) OrElse FilteredItem.PkgCost.ToString.Contains(TxtPkgCost.Text)))
                       Select FilteredItem`

The problem is that the query returns nothing even when the list is being populated.
At debugging, the list value is correct (populated with few items), but the query doesn't returning anything. I can't figure out what is wrong, so any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!
Ps. I'm using vb.net, but answers in C# are also wellcome

Comment: try to `trim` your `textbox` value,

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox: Thanks for the reply. But I'm getting the same results.

Comment: Can you add plain english examples of what's in the source lists and other items that you are referencing in the query at time of execution?

Comment: First of all I would separate things into UI, data and logic. This query is a mess.

Comment: @BrandonB: The source list contains custom objects called "Items", each one have properties like Name, Quantity, Item Code, etc.  it aims to check for the value of the textboxes ("txt***.Text") and filter the list to select only items matching those criteria, if any of the textboxes have some value. the query then populates a DGV control.

Comment: @ISAE please see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

To start off with, this answer is obviously not complete yet, so please hold off any downvotes until I finalize it. I have every intention of helping the OP if I can, however at this time there is no way for me to even begin helping out because the information needed is not present.

@ISAE, Can you please provide the following:

- hoping the `Items` being queried is a strongly typed DataTable; the class file for the `Items` object type, preferably the designer files also (.xsc, .xsd, and .xss)
- the forms' designer files and code behinds.

Alternatively, if the project can be put on GitHub, that would be even better. If you can't release all of that code, then really need to know enough to somewhat reconstruct what's going on. As one of the comments pointed out, that LINQ query is really messy and it's hard to dissect right now.

Comment: Thanks very much for giving from your time to help, and sorry for the delay, I was off for few days. Now for the question, I know I'll sound silly, but I've figured it out. `Items` is a list of Entities, Coming from another query that retrieves a `DbSet`. The problem was that the specific entity type wasn't part of the `DbContext`. I don't understand exactly how the Items list was populated at the first place, but after adding the item entity to the context everything goes just fine. Thank you again for the time!